How to attach persistent assumptions to function definitions in an elegant way
I am defining a parametrization of an SU(2) matrix and verifying its property to be in SU(2) as follows:
SU2[A_, B_, C_, D_ ] = { {A + B*I, -C + D*I}, {C + D*I, A - B*I}}
Options[SU2] = {"Assumptions" -> {A*A + B*B + C*C + D*D == 1}}
ComplexExpand [
  FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    SU2[A, B, C, D] . ConjugateTranspose [SU2[A, B, C, D]]] , 
   OptionValue[SU2, "Assumptions"]
   ]] // MatrixForm

This works very nicely but has one severe flaw, namely that the assumptions do not adjust with the renaming of the bound variables. Of course, the following does not work:
SU2[A_, B_, C_, D_ ] = { {A + B*I, -C + D*I}, {C + D*I, A - B*I}}
Options[SU2] = {"Assumptions" -> {A*A + B*B + C*C + D*D == 1}}
ComplexExpand [
  FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[
    SU2[X, B, C, D] . ConjugateTranspose [SU2[X, B, C, D]]] , 
   OptionValue[SU2, "Assumptions"]
   ]] // MatrixForm

I am looking for a way to attach assumptions to a function definition in such a manner that the assumptions also adjust when renaming variables.

How about SU2[A_, B_, C_, D_] := Block[{}, $Assumptions = $Assumptions && (A*A + B*B + C*C + D*D == 1); {{A + B*I, -C + D*I}, {C + D*I, A - B*I}}] ? Then FullSimplify works without explicitly specifying Assumptions. BUT it has some drawbacks : the global variable $Assumptions is changed, and you may have to restore it.

@A.Kato This certainly is an interesting approach and I learned something from it. However it is exactly confusion with the namespaces which made me search for a better solution. Thus I am not yet happy with this as a solution as it tampers with a global variable.
